# Как сделать адаптивный фон на часть экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать одну вещь. Есть некий фон, который должен равняться по центру блоков со свойством 
"display: inline-block;". Сайт должен сохранять адаптивность, фон должен растягиваться по ширине экрана. Выглядеть это должно как-то так:

На полный экран:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В мобильной версии:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синим цветом отмечены края окна браузера, красным - линия, по которой должен равняться фон. Можно ли реализовать это на чистом css или же придется прибегать к JS. Если да, то как? Спасибо.

Заготовка на CSS

```css
.bg-img { 

 z-index: -1;
 background-position: top;
 background-size: contain;
 position: absolute;
 /*min-height: 72.5vw;*/
 height:55rem;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```css
.header-content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.list {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-content {
    height: 40vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-content">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```